# Wordpress custom post type not showing in category template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, categories, custom-post-type

I'm encountering some strange issue when trying to display the list of custom post type in a category template. I have a category-*spettacoli*.php template that is supposed to list all *spettacoli* custom posts of a given category, but no result is being shown at all.

This is even stranger since I have another custom post type called *corsi* that is working perfectly (category template etc.) although the two custom post types category templates are almost identical.

Here's the code:

**functions.php (custom post types and category creation part)**

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

//add custom post types
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'corsi',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Corsi' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Corso' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'taxonomies' => array('category'), 
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        )
    );
    register_post_type( 'spettacoli',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Spettacoli' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Spettacolo' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'taxonomies' => array('category'), 
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        )
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// add custom post to category filter
function namespace_add_custom_types_spettacoli( $query ) {
    if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
            'post', 'spettacoli'
        ));
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types_spettacoli' );

function namespace_add_custom_types_corsi( $query ) {
    if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
            'post', 'corsi'
        ));
        return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types_corsi' );
```

**category-spettacoli.php (not working)**

```
<?php 
/*
 *  Spettacoli base archive template
 */
get_header(); ?>

<?php
    $cat_name = get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name;
?>

<h1><?php echo $cat_name; ?></h1>

<?php
   if ( have_posts() ) {
       while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            the_title();
            the_content();
       }
   }
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**category-corsi.php (working)**

```
<?php 
/*
 *  Corsi base archive template
 */
get_header(); ?>

<?php
    $cat_name = get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name;
?>

<h1><?php echo $cat_name; ?></h1>

<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            the_title();
            the_content();
        }
    }
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Categories have been created correctly and assigned correctly to all custom post types, so I'm guessing that is not the problem. 
Also no permalink refresh is solving anything..

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is Your issue solved OR Not?